# How to store sessions in MongoDB from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

I use `connect-mongo` module to store sessions from `express` in `mongodb`. Use it like this:

```
app.use(express.session({
    'secret': config.APP_SECRET,
    'store': new MongoStore({
        'db': db
    })
}));
```

Where:

```
var MongoStore = require(config.MODULES_DIR + 'connect-mongo')(express);
var db = mongoose.connection; // already connected as i use in in callback
```

But when session is used i get this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'open'
    at MongoStore._open_database (/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:174:15)
    at MongoStore._get_collection (/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:169:14)
    at MongoStore.get (/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:211:10)
    at Object.session [as handle] (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:314:11)
    at next (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.cookieParser [as handle] (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js:60:5)
    at next (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.urlencoded [as handle] (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:49:37)
    at next (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.json [as handle] (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:51:37)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a Mongoose connection, you need the aptly named [`mongoose_connection`](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#options) option:

```
new MongoStore({
  mongoose_connection : db 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always found it easier to connect using a MongoUri. Most DB services will provide one for you to use for your db. It should look something like this:

```
var mongoUri = 'mongodb://username:password@foo.mongohq.com/port/db'

app.use(express.session({
    store   : new MongoStore({
        url  : mongoUri
    })
}))
```